# Symfony Integrate Zend Lucene Search

Tags: zend-framework, search, symfony1, lucene

I've been following the Jobeet tutorial in order to integrate the Zend Lucene search into my Symfony project and I can't seem to get it to work.   I have added the following code to my config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php

```
class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{

  static protected $zendLoaded = false;

  static public function registerZend()
  {
    if (self::$zendLoaded)
    {
      return;
    }

    set_include_path(sfConfig::get('sf_lib_dir').'/vendor'.PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path());
    require_once sfConfig::get('sf_lib_dir').'/vendor/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
    Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    self::$zendLoaded = true;
  }
```

I have also added this code to my CarTable.class.php

```
    static public function getLuceneIndex()
    {
      ProjectConfiguration::registerZend();

      if (file_exists($index = self::getLuceneIndexFile()))
      {
        return Zend_Search_Lucene::open($index);
      }

      return Zend_Search_Lucene::create($index);
    }

    static public function getLuceneIndexFile()
    {
      return sfConfig::get('sf_data_dir').'/car.'.sfConfig::get('sf_environment').'.index';
    }
```

And lastly I have added the following code to my Car.class.php

```
    public function updateLuceneIndex()
    {
      $index = CarTable::getLuceneIndex();


      foreach ($index->find('pk:'.$this->getIditem()) as $hit)
      {
        $index->delete($hit->id);
      }


      if (!$this->getActivated())
      {
        return;
      }

      $doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();


      $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Keyword('pk', $this->getIditem()));


      $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnStored('title', $this->getTitle(), 'utf-8'));
      $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnStored('features', $this->getFeatures(), 'utf-8'));
      $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnStored('location_city', $this->getLocation_city(), 'utf-8'));
      $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnStored('location_state', $this->getLocation_state(), 'utf-8'));


      $index->addDocument($doc);
      $index->commit();
    }


    public function delete(Doctrine_Connection $conn = null)
    {
      $index = CarTable::getLuceneIndex();

      foreach ($index->find('pk:'.$this->getIditem()) as $hit)
      {
        $index->delete($hit->id);
      }

      return parent::delete($conn);
    }
```

And of course I added these few lines to the save function:

```
      $conn = $conn ? $conn : $this->getTable()->getConnection();
      $conn->beginTransaction();
      try
      {
        $ret = parent::save($conn);

        $this->updateLuceneIndex();

        $conn->commit();

        return $ret;
      }
      catch (Exception $e)
      {
        $conn->rollBack();
        throw $e;
      }
```

I have extracted the contents of the "library" folder of the Zend Framework into my lib/vendor/Zend folder.

But every time I run the command

```
php symfony doctrine:data-load
```

It runs all the way through and loads all of my fixtures but it doesn't create the folder with the index files in my data folder.   I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my reference (Jobeet Tutorial)  http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/17

By the way I'm using Symfony 1.4 (Doctrine).

Comment: Do you have activated cars in your fixtures?

Comment: Yes.   I have 100 of them and they are all set to 1 for the "Activated" field.

Comment: Can you make sure (with a well-placed `die()` or similar) that the updateIndex function gets called?

Comment: Ok I tried adding an item through the site itself and it pointed out where the problem was.   Instead of "Car" it needed to say "CarTable".   I have updated the original question to show the right terminology.  Now if I add a car through the site itself, it adds it to the index.  But the problem still remains where if I run that command to load the data from the fixtures, it creates the objects just fine, but it doesn't index them.  I'm not sure what else to do.  :(

Comment: Is there a way to start a log when you run that command so that maybe it can tell me where in the class file it's failing?  Or skipping?

Comment: Does your object's save function even get called with the fixture load?
Otherwise you could write a function that loops through each object in the database and calls updateLuceneIndex() for each one.

Comment: You are right.   The save function doesn't get called when adding fixtures.   I didn't realize that.   Thank you so much.